# When Importing a File, Error States File is not Named. Python

Tags: python-3.x

Fast Question

in my file i wrote
from foggerlib.frog import Frog

my datamember is self.F = frog.Frog(perameters)

line 13, in **init**()

self.F = frog.Frog(self, x, y, w, h, dx, dy, s, hg, vg)
NameError: name 'frog' is not defined

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported capital 'F' Frog.  You may be able to replace frog.Frog with simply Frog.

Comment: If that worked for you, feel free to contribute back to the community and accept the answer.  One of these days I should ask a question so I can see how this works...